# EditText.getText() returning empty string

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So this is another problem that has been brought up a million times, but I'm still doing something wrong.  Using EditText.getText() is returning an empty string.

I'm doing this in a small custom dialog I've made.  I'm building it with the AlertDialog Builder, which might be causing the issue?  I really don't know at this point.

Some things I've tried/notes on what I know about the issue:

- I'm checking for text in the OK button's click listener, so I'm not trying to get a value before there would be one, which was a common error I saw.
- I have ID's set for the EditText objects in my XML and the debugger seems to show that I'm referencing them properly.
- I've tried defining the EditText objects outside of the onCreateDialog method and that didn't change things (though I am curious which is better practice).
- Using EditText.setText() before getText() will allow it to return the argument used in setText(), but it doesn't seem to be fetching a value input by the user.

Here is my custom Dialog Fragment:

```
public class GPSLocationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_dialog, null);

        final EditText latitudeText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        final EditText longitudeText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.longitude);

        // Define the dialog
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_dialog, null))
                .setMessage("Manually input a GPS address")

                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Log.d("myTag", "Text: " + latitudeText.getText()); // This prints ""

                        // These throw errors since they're trying to parse "" as a double
                        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeText.getText().toString());
                        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeText.getText().toString());
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the Dialog from my Activity:

```
GPSLocationDialogFragment gpsDialog = new GPSLocationDialogFragment();

gpsDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "GPSDialog");
```

And here is my layout .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/longitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/longitude"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/latitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/latitude"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If more context is necessary I can share it, I tried to simplify to just the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_dialog, null))
```

to this:

```
builder.setView(view)
```

What's happening is that you inflate gps_dialog xml and turn its layout hierarchy into a View. Then you find the EditText's and a assign a reference to them.

However, by calling `setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_dialog, null))`
 instead of passing the View that you already inflated, and whose child EditText's you have a reference to, to the dialog, what you are doing is inflating a *new* version of the gps_dialog.xml and passing *that* to the dialog. The references that you have are to EditText's that aren't on the screen.

Comment: Thank you, this worked and was a very clear explanation of the problem and what the erroneous code was doing!